# how i scale this in the way that i want it to be?

Tags: modeling

as in the images appears, i want to scale (or maybe its not scale the option) this faces but exactly proportional (or whatever can be said) to the faces beside them.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Proportional editing (shortcut is O)?

Comment: your mesh is super messy, perhaps you're going a bit too fast

Comment: @moonboots fast how? why its messy =/ ?

Comment: @Mechanic nope i am not talking about proportional editing

Comment: @Michael Ben David, maybe it's all about snapping? I just guessing on your images. Maybe, if you rephrase your question (what exactly you want to get) it would be not a guesswork,

Comment: @Mechanic zoom and see carefully in the second image how the selected faces looks and i see the litle difference in the 1 fisrt picture